# Detect missing unittests

Tags: python, code-coverage, python-unittest, nose

I am refactoring a legacy Python project, which did not have any unittests.
Assuming a directory structure like this:

```
C:.
├───scripts
│       schema.sql
├───src
│   │   .coverage
│   │   bar.py
│   │   baz.py
│   │   foo.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   └───utils
│           __init__.py
└───tests
        .coverage
        test_foo.py
```

foo.py looks like:

```
import bar
import baz
import requests
import psycopg2
import os
import sys

print(requests.__file__)


def foo():
    return 'foo'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo())
```

test_foo.py looks like:

```
import unittest
import foo


class Test_Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        result = foo.foo()
        self.assertEqual(result, 'foo')
```

I've just defined tests for `foo.py`, running the unittests:

```
python.exe -m unittest discover -s . && coverage report -m
C:\data\...\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\data\myProject\src\bar.py       2      1    50%   2
C:\data\myProject\src\foo.py      11      4    64%   6-8, 12, 16
------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                             13      5    62%
```

Using nose, the output shows missing tests for packages within 'site-packages' as well which I dont want to see:

```
nosetests -w ..\src --cover-inclusive  --cover-tests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-html

Name                                    Stmts   Miss  Cover
-----------------------------------------------------------
bar.py                                      2      1    50%
baz.py                                      2      1    50%
certifi\__init__.py                         2      2     0%
...
decimal.py                                 10     10     0%
encodings\idna.py                         180    180     0%
hmac.py                                    60     60     0%
http\client.py                            756    756     0%
http\client.py                            756    756     0%
http\cookiejar.py                        1102   1102     0%
http\cookies.py                           248    248     0%
idna\__init__.py                            4      4     0%
idna\__init__.py                            4      4     0%
idna\core.py                              291    291     0%
idna\core.py                              291    291     0%
idna\idnadata.py                            4      4     0%
idna\idnadata.py                            4      4     0%
idna\intranges.py                          30     30     0%
idna\intranges.py                          30     30     0%
idna\package_data.py                        1      1     0%
idna\package_data.py                        1      1     0%
mimetypes.py                              194    194     0%
numbers.py                                134    134     0%
psycopg2\__init__.py                       22     22     0%
...
src\__init__.py                             0      0   100%
src\bar.py                                  2      1    50%
src\baz.py                                  2      1    50%
src\foo.py                                 11      2    82%
src\utils\__init__.py                       0      0   100%
stringprep.py                              65     65     0%
urllib3\__init__.py                        34     34     0%
...
-----------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                   14613  14600     1%
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

How do I see a regular unittest/coverage report and additionally files within the working directory which haven't been tested ?

Comment: Perhaps check out the `coverage` package. The output report is fantastic, highlighting the source code file with lines which have and have not been tested. [Linked here](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pytest.
Recreating your directory structure and optionally removing `import baz` in `foo.py`:

```
import bar                    
# import baz                  
import requests               
import psycopg2               
import os                     
import sys                    
                              
print(requests.__file__)      
                              
                              
def foo():                    
    return 'foo'              
                              
                              
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    print(foo())
```

Executing pytest:

```
pytest --cov-report html:cov_html --cov-report term-missing --cov=src tests/
```

Output:

```
===== test session starts 
... omitted output ...
collected 1 item

tests\test_foo.py .                                                                                                                                                                              [100%]

----------- coverage: platform win32, python 3.7.9 -----------
Name                    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------
src\__init__.py             0      0   100%
src\bar.py                  2      1    50%   2
src\baz.py                  2      2     0%   2-3
src\foo.py                 10      1    90%   16
src\utils\__init__.py       0      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                      14      4    71%
Coverage HTML written to dir cov_html
```

`pytest` shows 0% coverage for `baz.py`